# How to disable legend click to stop pie slice from disappearing in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to disable legend click to stop pie slice from disappearing in Highcharts??

See example here:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You do this by attaching a handler to the `legendItemClick` event and just returning `false`. This will prevent the default action which is to toggle the pie sector.

```
point: {
    events: {
        legendItemClick: function () {
            return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
        }
    }
}
```

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/mfras3r/3vVGB/1/

Comment: The mentioned fiddle no longer works in the current version of Highcharts. I've updated the code to work with version 3.0.2 - http://jsfiddle.net/mfras3r/3vVGB/1/

Comment: When I read the documentation, legendItemClick is not a method of `series.point.events` but directly of `series.events`: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events

Comment: how to disable the hand cursor and the selected slice when hovering the legend?

Answer (score 5):

```
pie: {
   showInLegend: true,
   allowPointSelect: false,
   point:{
       events : {
        legendItemClick: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
       }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pie: {
   showInLegend: true,
   allowPointSelect: false,  // disable selected
}
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not work. `allowPointSelect` is already false by default. This option is for a different feature, where clicking on a slice will slightly move it outwards. See https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.allowPointSelect