# highcharts pie window resize issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have pie within a pie and when i click on the legend of the pie .. the centre of the 2nd pie does not remain intact meaning the centre is changed now.... is it a known issue?[Before legend click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w32sw.png) ... i can post screenshots if it can help more... any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried setting different properties to the pie but nothing seems to work...

[After Legend click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrvkz.png)

Comment: Can you provide your code? A jsfiddle would probably be very helpful here.

Comment: For me works properly: http://jsfiddle.net/nkfu5r0k/, could you update my code with yours?

Answer (score 0):

This question elsewhere on StackOverflow may be helpful for you: [How to disable legend click to stop pie slice from disappearing in Highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833385/how-to-disable-legend-click-to-stop-pie-slice-from-disappearing-in-highcharts). In this instance, you're preventing the particular item in the legend from being "clickable," which prevents the associated pie slice from vanishing. I hope this helps you!