# Highcharts: disable allowPointSelect for only one pie slice

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

Is it possible to disable selection for only one pie slice and keep the others selectable? It looks like `allowPointSelect` can only be set to a whole series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that `allowPointSelect` can only be applied to an entire series for a pie chart, not specific data points in that series.

However, to prevent your users from selecting a specific pie slice, you can use a solution that's similar to what I found in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31308992/2596103):

```
  // pie slice on which you want to disable selections
  {
    name: 'Chrome',
    y: 24.03,
    // add event to prevent this slice from being selectable by the user
    events : {
      click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();     // prevent any action from occuring on "click" event
      }
    }
  },
```

Add this code to a specific slice to prevent anything from happening when the `click` event is triggered. Here's a fiddle with this addition in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/vscvowmu/

You could do the same for other types of events, such as `mouseOver', 'select', etc. (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series<pie>.data.events).

I hope this is helpful for you!